# Random js missing Magento

Tags: javascript, magento

I don't know why but my magento 1.9 is trying to load a random js called

```
media/js/7f9d8e1223f22976efa91a36dab2b9ee-1492776853.js
```

I tried to search where it loads this script but i didn't found anything. (I tried with linux command)

```
grep -rnw  -e '7f9d8e1223f22976efa91a36dab2b9ee-1492776853.js'
```

Response:

```
var/cache/mage--e/mage---39d_AA86E39A608AD7F4A14C00EA32A60248C31C23D6:186:script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.naturaloptics.com/media/js/7f9d8e1223f22976efa91a36dab2b9ee-1492776853.js"></script>
```

I don't know what is this file.... and this automatically loads on each file of my Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is Merged JS please check in your backend, 
`System -> Configuration -> Advanced (Developer)` and set to `No` for merging of js files that random file will not call again.
[image]